# Keyboard overlapping AnimatedList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using an [AnimatedList](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list) with `n` items in Flutter to create a chat.
My problem is, that every time I tap the Keyboard out it will overlay the latest messages. I already know this behaviour from other views where I used to solve it to wrap the container in a `SingleChildScrollView`. But in case of the `AnimatedList` I cannot wrap it into a `SingleChildScrollView` because it will error out with:

> Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Does anyone know what Widget to use that `AnimatedList` will be pushed to above the Keyboard that it won't hide the latest messages.

Another way would be to re-scroll the list to match the keyboard height, but this seems hacky.

Thanks

Edit: Used `ListView` in the end.

Comment: How did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @AkashGorai I used `ListView` eventually

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` in the Scaffold.

Comment: `ListView -> AnimatedList` does not seem like a correct structure.

Comment: But you tried with the resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false ?

Comment: Yes. Then it even does not move the `Send message` input like before. So the keyboard overlaps both.

Comment: Can we see your structure?